# Problema al exportar la base de datos en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Resulta que quiero exportar una base de datos sqlite en android studio a un archivo CSV. El error que da es que no encuentra el fichero o el directorio. El error en concreo es el siguiente:
/storage/emulated/0/ExportarSQLiteCSV/Libros.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

He revisado los permisos del android manifest y creo que tengo los necesarios

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.biblioteca">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Biblioteca">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Alta"
            android:exported="true"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Modificar"
            android:exported="true"> </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Además en el código hago una prueba para ver si existen tanto la carpeta como el fichero y en ambos casos me dicen que sí existen.
Este es el main:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, "bdlibros", null, 1);

        btnAlta = findViewById(R.id.btn_alta);
        btnOrdenarPor = findViewById(R.id.btn_ordenarPor);
        btnExportarDatos = findViewById(R.id.btn_exportarDatos);
        tvRegistros = findViewById(R.id.tv_registros);
        tvOrdenarPor = findViewById(R.id.tv_orden);

        pedirPermisos();
        numRegistros();
        consultarListaLibros();

        adaptador = new MiAdaptador(listaLibros, this, this);

        //crear objeto adaptador
        lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
        rv.setAdapter(adaptador);

        resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(//Necesitamos el result launcher para poder invocarlo retornando datos
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();//Para acceder a los datos devueltos
                        if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){//Si ha sido result_ok devolvemos los parametros
                            if (data != null && (!data.getStringExtra("TITULO").equals(""))) {//Si no es nulo hacemos las acciones que sean con los datos devueltos
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setId(data.getIntExtra("ID", -1));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setCategoria(data.getStringExtra("TIPO"));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setTitulo(data.getStringExtra("TITULO"));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setAutor(data.getStringExtra("AUTOR"));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setIdioma(data.getStringExtra("IDIOMA"));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setFormato(data.getStringExtra("FORMATO"));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setFechaLecturaIni(data.getLongExtra("FECHA INICIO", -1));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setFechaLecturaFin(data.getLongExtra("FECHA FIN", -1));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setValoracion(data.getFloatExtra("VALORACION", -1));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setPrestadoA(data.getStringExtra("PRESTADO"));
                                listaLibros.get(pos).setNotas(data.getStringExtra("NOTAS"));
                                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        adaptador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selección: " +
                        listaLibros.get(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getTitulo(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pos = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                Intent actividad = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Modificar.class);
                actividad.putExtra("ID", listaLibros.get(pos).getId());
                actividad.putExtra("TIPO", listaLibros.get(pos).getCategoria());
                actividad.putExtra("TITULO", listaLibros.get(pos).getTitulo());
                actividad.putExtra("AUTOR", listaLibros.get(pos).getAutor());
                actividad.putExtra("IDIOMA", listaLibros.get(pos).getIdioma());
                actividad.putExtra("FORMATO", listaLibros.get(pos).getFormato());
                actividad.putExtra("FECHA INICIO", listaLibros.get(pos).getFechaLecturaIni());
                actividad.putExtra("FECHA FIN", listaLibros.get(pos).getFechaLecturaFin());
                actividad.putExtra("VALORACION", listaLibros.get(pos).getValoracion());
                actividad.putExtra("PRESTADO", listaLibros.get(pos).getPrestadoA());
                actividad.putExtra("NOTAS", listaLibros.get(pos).getNotas());
                resultLauncher.launch(actividad);
            }
        });
        
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        btnAlta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent actividad = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alta.class);
                //resultLauncher.launch(actividad);
                startActivity(actividad);

                //Para redirigir a una página web
                //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://code.tutsplus.com"));
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnOrdenarPor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentoOrdenarPor fop = new FragmentoOrdenarPor();
                fop.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fop");
            }
        });

        btnExportarDatos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                exportarDatos();
            }
        });

    }
```

Esta es la función donde quiero exportar:

```
public void exportarDatos() {
        File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExportarSQLiteCSV");

        boolean isCreateCarpeta = false;
        if(!carpeta.exists()) {
            isCreateCarpeta = carpeta.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Existe la carpeta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        File archivo = new File(carpeta, "Libros.csv");
        boolean isCreate = false;
        if(!archivo.exists()) {
            isCreate = archivo.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        checkExternalStoragePermission();

        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(archivo);
            conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, "bdlibros", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Buenas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_LIBROS, null);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fila.toString() + " a " + fila.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(fila != null && fila.getCount() != 0) {
                fila.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getInt(0) + " \n");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(1) + " \n");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(2) + " \n");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(3) + " \n");
                } while(fila.moveToNext());
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No hay registros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            fila.close();
            db.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Se creó exitosamente el archivo CSV", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Aquí están los métodos donde doy los permisos de forma manual:

```
public void pedirPermisos() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
    }

    private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
        }
    }
```

Me gustaría saber porqué se da este error y cómo podría solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Comment: ¿Dónde ocurre el error exactamente? ¿Al intentar qué acción?

Comment: El error ocurre en el filewriter al declararlo e inicializarlo. Tiene razón quiero exportar la base de datos a un archivo CSV

Comment: Prueba a agregar esto dentro de `application`  en tu archivo de manifiesto: **`<android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">`**, [lee lo que dice la documentación al respecto.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app), no sé si sea tu caso.

Comment: He descubierto el error. Resulta que a partir del TargetSDK 29 el método Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() está obsoleto en API 29 por lo que al manifiesto hay que añadirle esta línea: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Muchas gracias, sisi era justo por eso. Aquí está la explicación https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Comment: Sí. Lee el apartado completo de la doc y revisa los enlaces (lo he agregado al final de la respuesta), para que puedas configurar adecuadamente tu lectura de archivos según las versiones a las que tu App estará orientada.

Answer (score 2):

[Según la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app):

> Si la app se orienta a Android 10 (nivel de API 29) o versiones
> anteriores, puedes inhabilitar temporalmente el almacenamiento
> específico de la app de producción. Sin embargo, si orientas tu app a
> Android 10, debes configurar el valor de
> `requestLegacyExternalStorage` como `true` en el archivo de manifiesto
> de tu app:
>
> ```
> <manifest ... >
>   <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
>        Android 10. -->
>   <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
>     ...
>   </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Por tanto, agrega esto, dentro de `application`  en el `Manifest`:

```
<android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

### Muy importante

Conviene que leas la documentación completa, y revises los enlaces:

> **Precaución**: Después de actualizar tu app para orientarla a Android 11 (nivel de API 30), [el sistema ignora el atributo
> `requestLegacyExternalStorage`](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage) cuando la app se ejecuta en
> dispositivos Android 11, por lo que esta debe ser compatible con el
> almacenamiento específico y la [migración de datos de app](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage) para los
> usuarios de esos dispositivos.
>
> Si deseas probar el comportamiento de una app que se orienta a Android
> 10 o versiones anteriores cuando usas almacenamiento específico,
> puedes establecer el valor de `requestLegacyExternalStorage` en
> `false`. Si realizas pruebas en un dispositivo con Android 11, también
> puedes [usar marcas de compatibilidad de apps](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#test-scoped-storage) para probar el
> comportamiento de tu app con o sin almacenamiento específico.